# Mysql where clause exact match returns not exact - "sàvko" = "savko"

Tags: mysql

Field have charset "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"

How I can get only "savko" when I doing `where field = 'savko'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generally like `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` on your field but just want to do this one test in a different collation,

```
... WHERE field COLLATE utf8mb4_bin = 'savko'
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it after change field collation to `'utf8mb4_bin'`